# Why is session[:user_id] automatically secure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, railstutorial.org

I am presently following the ***railstutorial*** and I have learnt in ***Chapter 8*** that storing the user's id in the session automatically encrypts the info. One question is this, How is it automatically secured? What performed the encryption under the hood. Why is the cookies method (introduced later) not automatically secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Rails 4, EncryptedCookieStore is used by default to encrypt any session value in a cookie, that's why you have a config/secrets.yml file. Session values are encrypted by RoR API.

You can learn more about how rails handles the session in [Ruby on Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)

Comment: I am just wondering why the cookies method cannot be automatically secured

Comment: It is, since rails 4.